# No indexing with `glossaries` and MakeIndex

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, makeindex

I'm using the `glossaries` package to define a list of acronyms, and I cannot get the `.idx` and `.ind` files to write themselves. This is my MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{np}{\textsc{np}}{nom propre}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\printglossary[title=Abréviations dans les gloses morphosyntaxiques,type=acronym,nopostdot]

Il s'agit d'un \acrshort{np}.

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

And here is what I get on the console log when, after compiling to pdf a first time, I run MakeIndex:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2016] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file myDoc.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in myDoc.ind.
Transcript written in myDoc.ilg.
```

That means that when compiling a second time, the glossary won't print. I tried using `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossary`, but this brings another problem (not on this MWE) that I'll address another time.

Comment: You haven't used `\index` anywhere in the document so the `.idx` file is empty, which means there's no index (but you also haven't used `\printindex` either). The glossary files have different extensions and you need to call `makeindex` with those extensions. If you have Perl installed run `makeglossaries myDoc` otherwise run `makeglossaries-lite myDoc`.